# Creating Oauth2 Access Token in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, oauth-2.0, access-token

```
OAuthClientRequest request = OAuthClientRequest
            .tokenLocation("url")
            .setGrantType(GrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
            .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
            .setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET)
            .buildBodyMessage();


//create OAuth client that uses custom http client under the hood
OAuthClient oAuthClient = new OAuthClient(new URLConnectionClient());

OAuthJSONAccessTokenResponse oAuthResponse = oAuthClient.accessToken(request, OAuthJSONAccessTokenResponse.class);
```

This is a solution to generate OAuth 2 Access Token easily. Can Any one suggest a an equivalent solution using org.springframework.security.oauth2?  Since our's is Bank side application, it won't support apche.oltu.  Thank u in advance.

Can Any one suggest a similar solution using org.springframework.security.oauth2?  Since our's is Bank side application, it won't support apche.oltu.  Thank u in advance.